# Python: Unicode string and Escape sequences

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode

Lets say I have a text file containing a line with double back slashes. For example,

```
...
3\\/4
...
```

When I open this file in Python and try to process the lines, I get the following issue:

```
f = open("example.txt")
for line in f:
    print(line)

#prints "3\/4" instead of "3\\/4"!!
```

So I guess when unicode is converted to a Python string, the double back slashes are escaped to single back slash... How do I prevent this??

I know when I'm creating a string, I can do something like this:

```
x = r"3\\/4"
```

But I'm not sure how I can do this for a string ***variable*** ("line" in this case)?

Thanks

Comment: I get `3\\/4`, just what is expected. Are you sure your file contains a double backslash?

Answer (score 2):

You would use Python's raw string notation by adding `r` as well ..

```
>>> uni = ur"a\\/b"
>>> print(uni)
a\\/b
```

Comment: Sorry I changed my question. Your answer works, but I have a slightly different situation..please read my edited question. thanks!

Comment: A raw string literal is only used to create string values. You can't turn an existing string "raw".

Answer (score 1):

If a file contains that content, that's what will print.  There is no issue.

```
c:\>type x.txt
3\\/4
c:\>py
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open('x.txt') as f:
...  for line in f:
...   print(line)
...
3\\/4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `print(repr(line))` instead of `print(line)`. Hope this helps:

```
>>> a='\\anc'
>>> print(a)
\anc
>>> print(repr(a))
'\\anc'
```